# netcdf daily data to monthly raster layers

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster, netcdf

I have a netcdf (.nc) file of 95GB which consisted of daily data for a 50 years period. I tried to process this with ArcGIS (Multidimension tools – MakeNetCDFRasterLayer command) and it was not functioned. Then I tried with QGIS by adding .nc file as a raster layer and ‘save as’ as Gtiff. This also crashed at the middle of the process.
.nc file data are in daily basis and I want to create separate monthly raster layers by using daily data. 
Can someone help me solve this?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to use the [NCO tools](http://nco.sourceforge.net/) to do the averaging. Something like this should work to do two months:

```
ncwa -a time -d time,"2010-01-01 01:00","2010-02-01" -O -D 1 $url mean_01.nc
ncwa -a time -d time,"2010-02-01 01:00","2010-03-01" -O -D 1 $url mean_02.nc
ncea -O mean01.nc mean02.nc test.nc
```

For 50 years, obviously you would do this as a loop using shell or python.  Note that NCO can be difficult to build, so definitely check out the [binaries page](http://nco.sourceforge.net/#Binaries).  There is a native Windows build there, in addition to Mac and Linux.

Another way would be to just write a little python program using NetCDF4-Python, since that's included in the [ESRI Multidimentional Supplemental Tools](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9f963f362fe5417f87d44618796db938)